# How to use multiple model instances in views in django?

Tags: django

I have created a website where when a user upload an image, I detect objects on that image and show them. So here is my model:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
    imgfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d',default='settings.MEDIA_ROOT/default/default.jpg')
    catagory = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="unknow")
```

The docfile is the original image, imgfile is an image where I label object in an image, catagory is the category of the object.

My problem is that there might be multiple objects in an image, thus I might have multiple Document instances in my views, but I don't know exactly how many instances I need in advance because this depends on the detection results.

So how can I implement this? And if I can use a Document list in views, how can I show contents in this list in my html template? Thx.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use Django's [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/) which let you create/edit multiple object instances at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your models a little:

```
class BaseImage(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
class Document(models.Model):
    base_image = models.ForeignKey(BaseImage)
    imgfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d',default='settings.MEDIA_ROOT/default/default.jpg')
    catagory = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="unknow")
```

That way you can query all the objects extracted from your base image with:

```
my_image = BaseImage.objects.get(pk=some_id)
my_extracted_objects = my_image.document_set.all()
```

It is possible then in your view to send that queryset in your context and in template display each one:

```
{% for document_object in my_extracted_objects %}
    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ document_object.imgfile.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

If i am missing something or misunderstood the question, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks!, that's exactly what I need. But I made some changes, for convenience I put them in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @cdvv7788 said, I made some changes:
In my views, I use:

```
my_images = Document.objects.filter(base_image=newdoc.id)
```

Where newdoc is a BaseImage instance, i.e. image uploaded by the user.

While in my html templates, I have the code below to list all detection result:

```
{%for image in my_images%}
    <img src="{{image.imgfile.url}}">
{%endfor%}
```